# Showing a survey issue using onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I would like to add an survey to appear right before a user leaves a page.  I thought I could hook it up using the onbeforeunload event, but although I am able to capture the event, I see a dialog like this. [image]  How do I prevent a dialog like this from appearing?

Please note that I have tried returning false from the method, but it still shows the dialog below.

Comment: onbeforeunload is not like other event handlers: it shows what you return. so what you describe is what the onbeforeunload event does: it shows a dialog. if you don't want the dialog, don't bind an event to onbeforeunload. to wit: you cannot just force a person to stay on your page while showing them whatever you want.

Comment: While @dandavis is correct, you can catch MANY cases of the person trying to navigate away from the page through links and forms by using event delegation on the document.  It won't catch someone navigating away through the back/forward buttons, bookmarks and typing into the address bar.